# Cleaning my Macbook screen *under* the shield

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have a Macbook Pro 13" Unibody Early 2011. In the last few months the transparent shield protecting the screen has separated at the bottom letting dust in. It's still attached at the top.

- How can I safely clean the screen under the shield?
- Once I've cleaned it, how can I keep the shield from separating?

Answer (score 1):

To do this the risk of further damage is rather high as I had to do this before on the same Mac. You will need a heat gun to heat the edge of the screen so you can pull it off then after it is separated you will need microfiber cloths and denatured alcohol (available in the paint section of any store) to wipe the LCD and glass cover perfectly clean. After finished you can use your glue of choice to put it back together however keep in mind pretty much any glue you use will not come back off without breaking something, so there is no turning back. Personally, either use an external screen or buy a new one off eBay (which is what I did). I found with mine it separated because the hinge cracked and wasn't able to tell this till after I opened it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The screen and hinges are still fine, and the dust problem is minor, everything is usable. I think I'll leave it be for now.